# Firebase storage: Image file types not showing after upload. How do I use the image?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

When I use an npm package like google-cloud or multer-gcs to upload a file to firebase storage bucket (that uses google cloud storage under the hood..) the file gets uploaded. However, the file does not show and image type(MIME). Also, how do I use the image in my *node.js* application?

**Here is the code to upload image to firebase bucket. Used multer to handle file upload..**

```
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');
var gcs = require( 'multer-gcs' );

var storage = gcs({
    filename    : function( req, file, cb ) {
        cb( null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    },
    bucket      : 'p****n-bcXX3.appspot.com', // Required : bucket name to upload 
    projectId   : 'p****n-bcXX3', // Required : Google project ID 
    keyFilename: './p****n-5cbc725XXXXd.json', // Required : JSON credentials file for Google Cloud Storage 
    acl : 'publicread' // Optional : Defaults to private 
});
```

**In my routes:**

```
router.post('/food/create', [authChecker, gcsUpload.single('food_image')], function(req, res, next) {
    Controllers.create_food(req, res);
});
```

When I upload file directly to the bucket, type shows clearly. What's the catch here?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [multer-gcs](https://github.com/jahmed76/multer-gcs) doesn't support the ability to add custom metadata to a file. If you use [gcloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node) directly, you'd do something like this:

```
var options = {
  destination: 'new-image.png',
  metadata: {
    contentType: 'image/png'
  }
};

bucket.upload('local-image.png', options, function(err, file) {
  // Your bucket now contains:
  // - "new-image.png" (with the contents of `local-image.png')

  // `file` is an instance of a File object that refers to your new file.
});
```

I'd file an issue with the developer of `multer` and ask them to support metadata uploads along side blob uploads, especially since `gcloud` already supports the ability to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I was not using the `metadata` in options. However, upon explicitly setting those options, I am now able to update the file type metadata on firebase. I also needed to set `predefinedAcl` option as `'publicread'` to make the public url visible to anyone and render on any browser. 
In fact, I needed to use the options in the `createWriteStream` rather than in bucket.upload method as I am uploading the file with _multer_ and receiving it as blob. Thanks a lot for that wonderful hint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing now to handle the file upload.

```
req.file.modifiedname = (Math.random().toString(36)+'00000000000000000').slice(2, 10) + Date.now() + path.extname(req.file.originalname);
var options = {
  metadata: {
    contentType: req.file.mimetype
  },
  predefinedAcl : 'publicread'
};

var blob = bucket.file(req.file.modifiedname);
var blobStream = blob.createWriteStream(options);

blobStream.on('error', function (err) {
  return next(err);
});

blobStream.on('finish', function() {
  publicUrl = format(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/%s/%s',
    bucket.name, blob.name
  );
  req.file.gcsfileurl = publicUrl;
  console.log(req.file.gcsfileurl);
  next();
});

blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
```